# How to use composition to generate random variates?

Tags: random-variables

I want to know how to use composition to generate random variates whose cdf and pdf are as follows.
[CDF and PDF of the aimed distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptKyU.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *composition* in this context?

Comment: That is a method to generate a random variates by using U(0,1). Just like inverse transform, convolution or acceptance-rejection algorithm.